# simplify and reform multidimensional python array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I have got an array, which looks like this:

```
[array([[55.       ,  0.2443461]], dtype=float32), array([[-51.       ,   2.8972466]], dtype=float32), array([[-10.       ,   2.8972466]], dtype=float32), array([[221.       ,   0.2268928]], dtype=float32), array([[2.2000000e+02, 2.0943952e-01]], dtype=float32)]
```

I would like to change it in a way that gives me two arrays: one with the first value of each of the entries  and one with the second.

So I want to the first array to look like this:

```
[55, -51, -10, 221, 1.2000000e+02]
```

And the second to look like this:

```
[0.2443461, 2.8972466, 2.8972466, 0.2268928, 2.0943952e-01]
```

I have found a way to do this using a loop, but I would like to avoid loops as much as possible, because the real arrays might be way bigger than the one I used in this example and if my code runs too slow I might get other problems. Is it possible to do it using indexing? If so: how?

The loop I used:

```
for x in range(lines_len):
        lines_angles.append(lines[x][0][1])
        lines_dist.append(lines[x][0][0])
```

Comment: is it an array of arrays or a list of arrays? and where does ```1.2000000e+02``` come from?

Comment: This looks like numpy arrays. Have you tried numpy.reshape? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: if it is an array of arrays, you can do it with indexing: ```array[:, 0, 0]``` and ```array[:, 0, 1]``` respectively

Comment: For type() I got "list" so I guess it is an list of arrays.
The values are polar coordinates of lines I got using cv2.HoughLines function. The first number is the distance, the second the angle.

Comment: @Sorbet Yes. There is no error showing up in the terminal, but also no result.

Comment: @Nin17 I am not sure. It should be a line in polar coordinates found by cv.HoughLines. Such values seldom show up, but it might be that a line just lays that way.

Comment: but you say ```I have an array which looks like this:``` and ```1.2000000e+02``` is not in that array but then ```1.2000000e+02``` is in your expected output I guess its just a typo

Comment: you can just convert the list to a numpy array and use the slicing method I suggested

Comment: @Nin17 It is in the array, but the array was too long, so you need to scroll in the code block to see it. I wasn't sure how to better format it.
Also your proposal with converting the array to np worked. Thank you very much! If you want to write it again as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list of `np.array`s, but a list support only integer indices or slices. So, convert to an `np.array` before using three indices:

```
lines = np.array(lines)

lines_dist = lines[:,0,0]
 # [ 55. -51. -10. 221. 220.]

lines_angles = lines[:,0,1] 
 # [0.2443461  2.8972466  2.8972466  0.2268928  0.20943952]
```